# 404: NOT_FOUND on Vercel deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, server, vercel

I have build a web3 application using chakra-UI and three.js. I have added a metamask integration to the website, which helps to mint the NFTs on smart contract.

When I do,

```
npm run dev
```

On my machine, my code is running extremely smoothly. I don't see any errors on my `localhost:3000` whereas when I am deploying the website using vercel, I am getting this error again and again which says **Code NOT_FOUND**
Here's the screenshot of that error:

[image: Error Image]

I deployed the website through my VSCode terminal using the

```
vercel
```

command.

I selected everything as default which came after executing this command.

[Click here to learn more about this error](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/frequently-asked-questions#why-do-i-see-a-404-error-when-accessing-my-deployment) didn't helped either.

I also tried to deploy this by going physically on vercel website and importing the github repo, but that also didn't worked.

The error page URL is:- https://minting-website-frontend.vercel.app/

Can anyone please help me overcome this error, I am stuck here for so long now

Comment: Check the "FRAMEWORK PRESET" under "Build & Development Settings" inside your Project Settings, so that it matches the one you're using locally (Next.js).

Comment: @JuanMarco Yes, I added Next.js in my framework preset and redeployed the website again. But there's still not any development on the problem. It still shows error 404

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've experienced this, and what I did to solve the problem was:

1. create a vercel.json file in my project.
2. Enter the following code in the vercel.json file

```json
{
    "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/index.html" }]
}
```

3. re-deploy the project

Comment: Please explain this

Comment: I was several hours with this issue, thanks mate!

Comment: I found info here but not sure how actually it fixes the 404 issue: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/rewrites

Comment: Does anyone know why this is working with single slash, but don`t with two slashes? I mean "website/account" - OK, ""website/account/profile" - 404?

Comment: This didn't work but setting the framework preset did.

Answer (score 6):

Go to vercel project settings->General->Build & Development Settings
and choose whatever framework your project is using
in my case My project was using Next js but it was chosen Others.
So when i changed it from others to Next Js problem solved

Comment: You can also add a vercel.json file to the root of your project add your framework there. https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're looking at the good URL?

You need to run `vercel --prod` to deploy to production, otherwise you're just deploying a preview version.

Can you please share the output of the `vercel` command in your terminal?

Comment: Yeah, well apparently there were some issues in the code. First, there was a spelling mistake in package.json, for `build:next-build`, I have no Idea how there can be a spelling mistake in this, lol(It's default when we create a next app) So probably that was the reason that it was not showing anything. After doing this, I ran `npm run build` which showed certain warnings, like passHref missing, unused imports and one const. component was initialised with small letter(e.g I wrote "home", instead of "Home"). Than I ran `vercel` and selected "Next.js" as suggested by @JuanMarco; Successful!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but with a project build with Svelte (not SvelteKit).

what worked for me was:

in Vercel dashboard, open the project. Goto project settings. In **Build & Development Settings** section, change **Framework Preset** to **other**.

I know there is Svelte option too but it was not worked for me. I am a back end dev and still new to the front end stuff but that was the fix for mine.

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this issue for too long but my issue was that my pages weren't pushed to production. Use this as a reminder to ensure the pages you're linking to are also in production

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35557664)