# How to integrate Vercel with Azure Repos?

Tags: azure, vercel, azure-repos

I am considering using Vercel for my front-end architecture but at the moment my codebase is hosted in Azure Repos.

Is there a way to integrate Azure Repos with Vercel?

Comment: Does this work for you Imported a GitHub project into azure Devops (vercel work linked to github) set up a new vercel project with no github connection, created the pipeline and ran it, it connects and runs for around a minute before failing with the error Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1 . Bearing in mind this exact code works from github to vercel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With the following, integrating vercel with Azure Devops is possible

- **From vercel docs**,there are detailed guidelines for Deploying Azure DevOps Pipelines with Vercel. https://vercel.com/docs/deployments/git/vercel-for-azure-pipelines.
- **The Vercel Deployment Extension** is now available through the *Visual Studio Marketplace.*
  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vercel.vercel-deployment-extension.

Comment: Does this work for you Imported a GitHub project into azure Devops (vercel work linked to github) set up a new vercel project with no github connection, created the pipeline and ran it, it connects and runs for around a minute before failing with the error Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
. Bearing in mind this exact code works from github to vercel

Comment: Do you have to build your project in Azure devops before using the plugin, and is using the default working folder correct? I also get errors

Comment: @MicroMan, the docs specify that you use an emty vercel project without git integration. I also encountered Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1. Then I went to deployment in the vercel project checked for errors and rectified them. The errors were in code for example an asset named login.png instead of login.PNG. I commited changes and ran again. The last fix was to specify the framework in the project settings. I was using next.js yet 'other' was the selected framework. After the fixes it worked.

Comment: @BankMan101, when you use the Vercel Deployment Extension, everything is catered for you plus building. Your pipeline does the work. If the project is not nested then you don't specify the working folder. Try following the docs step by step , at first using their 'pipeline-code' before making a complex pipeline. The other key thing is to also specify the framework you are using in the project settings in the dashboard as the default one is 'other' . My nextjs project was not working untill I specified the framework.

Comment: [This_Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378572/404-not-found-on-vercel-deployment) helped me fix the 404-issue after deployment. I specified the framework I used.

Answer (score 3):

This is the closest I have come to a viable solution to deploy Azure Repos on Vercel but it involves using Azure CI/CD pipelines.

https://vercel.com/guides/using-vercel-cli-for-custom-workflows

There is a significant drawback, with this approach you will not be able to toggle between deployments with a click of a button.