How to deploy node js express app on Vercel?
I have built an app using Node js, Express and typescript. npm run build builds the app and npm start serves the app. It works perfectly on local but I am having trouble when deploying it to the Vercel.
Here is my packages.json script
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/server.js",
    "build": "swc src -d dist --source-maps --copy-files",
    "serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node dist/server.js",
  },

My folder structure.

dist/server.js is my root file.
When I deploy the code it returns
404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND ID: bom1::fw9qg-1722258606228-23fe271eb94c

Hi, Please provide the rewrites in version.json if not done. You may please see a similar post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71378572/404-not-found-on-vercel-deployment
